# IE11>F12>Emulation> Some times it show 'Via local compatibility view settings' and some time shows 'Via intranet compatibility settings'.Why is that?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

In Internet Explorer 11, when I go to Emulation from F12 developer tools, some times it show 'Via local compatibility view settings' and some time shows 'Via intranet compatibility settings'.Why is that?

Actually for my webpage I have used inline style-

{ 
position: relative, 
TOP: expression(document.getElementById('div_LTA_Upper').scrollTop) 
}

But somehow this only works when document mode is 'Via intranet compatibility settings' and not when it is 'Via local compatibility view settings'. This is just my observation so far. It is possible that root cause is entirely something else but still it would help if I can understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Document mode**

F12 tools in Internet Explorer 11 has simplified the complex matrix of browser and document modes from earlier versions into a single option: the document mode.

**Via local compatibility view settings**: The site was manually added to the [Compatibility View settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg622935).

**Via intranet compatibility settings**: The "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" box is checked in the [Compatibility View settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg622935).

If your webpage is not displaying in the Document mode you expect, you have cleared any manual changes from the Emulation tool, and you are not shown one of the Document mode reasons from the list above, it may have been assigned a different Document mode by your enterprise IT department.

Reference:

[Document mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255001(v=vs.85)#mode)